I am building sound processing for flutter app and api on nodejs backend by mediasoup use Gstreamser
Currently I am building a stream that I am using to stream audio from the App, mediasoup client, to the nodejs API via
Mediasoup server. I am using the audio processing library using Gstreamer and have a problem that I cannot solve: balancing the sound between the phone's microphone and the mp4 beat when exporting to the app has 2 problems:

The delay when playing back to the app is 100 milliseconds compared to the actual request of the app which is <=20 milliseconds.
Sound balance between mp4 music and sound from the phone's microphone.
I want to order a rewrite of part 2 above and add audio customization on the Flutter app including customization bars:


Echo.

Sound volume.
Music volume


Reverb:

Mix.
Room Size.
*Damp.


Band Equalizers
Noise Reduce
Send to API server for processing through Gstreamser library.
Can anyone help me?

